# NSNumberFormatter numberFromString is adding a small fraction when converting certain numbers

Tags: ios, type-conversion, nsnumberformatter

I'm seeing some strange bugs in my iPhone app that I have narrowed down to my use of NSNumberFormatter.

A stripped down example...

In Xcode playground I have:

```
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
//numberFormatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle - does not change behavior

let numberString = "546000.06"

let number: NSNumber = numberFormatter.numberFromString(numberString)!

print("number: \(number)")

let number1: NSNumber = NSDecimalNumber(string: numberString)

print("number1: \(number1)")
```

This is the output:

```
number: 546000.0600000001
number1: 546000.06
```

Note that setting the numberStyle to .DecimalStyle doesn't change anything.

This issue only happens for certain numeric values (for example, 8.03 is another one). I thought NSNumberFormatter was safe for this type of conversion and I haven't seen much noise about this issue on the internet so I want to assume it is something I am doing wrong.

Can anyone explain what I am seeing?  Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I get that but I thought these iOS NSNumber classes handled that. Seems to me to be a large part of the reason for their existance.

Comment: High precision decimals is the reason for `NSDecimalNumber`'s existence.  `NSNumber` is just a wrapper around primitive values.

Comment: If i convert the parsed NSNumber to an NSDecimalNumber using any of the decimal, double, or float-based NSDecimalNumber constructors, the resulting NSDecimalNumber is inaccurate.  Are you saying NSNumberFormatter cannot accurately get me from String to NSDecimalNumber?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is an issue with NSNumberFormatter. There are certain values where this rounding error creeps up. In the XCode 7.2.1 playground, it shows up around 8.03.

One way that I've solved this is to round the decimal number. Since the difference is +/- a tiny amount, rounding to 4 fraction places should work. You can use various rounding modes. In this example I used RoundPlain.

```
var initialValue = NSDecimalNumber(string: "7")
let handler = NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: NSRoundingMode.RoundPlain, scale: 4, raiseOnExactness: false, raiseOnOverflow: false, raiseOnUnderflow: false, raiseOnDivideByZero: false) 
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()

for index in 1...300 {    
    initialValue = initialValue.decimalNumberByAdding(0.01)
    let stringValue = "\(initialValue)"

    var number = numberFormatter.numberFromString(stringValue)
    var decimalNumber: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: number!.decimalValue)
    decimalNumber = decimalNumber.decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior(handler)

    print("stringValue = \(stringValue), decimalNumber = \(decimalNumber), number = \(number!)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing a rounding error.

If you would like to display a number to the user with two fraction digits, set `maximumFractionDigits`:

```
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

let firstNumber = NSNumber(float:546000.06)
let firstNumberString = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(firstNumber)!

let secondNumber = NSNumber(float:5.1337)
let secondNumberString = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(secondNumber)!

print("firstNumber: \(firstNumberString)")
print("secondNumber: \(secondNumberString)")
```

The output will be:

```
"firstNumber: 546000.06\n"
"secondNumber: 5.13\n"
```

If you try to parse a number from a string, then you are all set.

```
let thirdNumber = numberFormatter.numberFromString("546000.06")!
print("thirdNumber \(thirdNumber.className): \(thirdNumber)")
```

The last line prints the description of the object itself (w/ rounding error):

```
"thirdNumber __NSCFNumber: 546000.0600000001\n"
```

### Update (2016-03-18)

You want to parse the following string:

```
let currencyString = "$546,000.06"
```

First, we create a formatter with a `locale` and `.CurrencyStyle`. Be aware that the `locale` depends on the string you try to parse and not on the system you are running on.

```
let currencyFormatter = NSNumberFormatter.init()
currencyFormatter.locale = NSLocale.init(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
```

We can now use the formatter to prase the string.

```
let currencyNumber = currencyFormatter.numberFromString(currencyString)!
```

You are now free to store this object, for example in CoreData. However, if you wan't to present the value to the user (or print it on the console), you *have* to use a `NSNumberFormatter`. If you print the object directly, the `description` (or `debugDescription`) of the object is used.

So, let's create another formatter to print the value of your `NSNumber` object:

```
let outputFormatter = NSNumberFormatter.init()
outputFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 10
```

Using many fraction digits should print any possible rounding errors. But

```
print("Number: \(outputFormatter.stringFromNumber(currencyNumber)!)")
```

outputs the desired result:

```
"Number: 546000.06\n"
```

What you have seen is the result of the internal representation of an `NSNumber` object (with `description`/`debugDescription`).

Comment: Unfortunately, setting maximumFractionDigits doesn't seem to help my cause.  I want to parse the number and then use it (not necessarily reformat it)... but it has the rounding error (just like your example).

Comment: What do you mean by "use it"? `NSNumber` shouldn't be used for arithmetic operations; use `NSDecimalNumber` instead.

Comment: Use it = I want to take the parsed number and then (store it in core data, use it for arithmetic, print it, do whatever I need to).  The only reason I use NSNumber above is because that is what the NSNumberFormatter provides and is the most basic example of the problem I am seeing.  In my specific app use case I am parsing currency so I can't just do NSDecimalNumber(string: "546000.06"). I need to parse using the formatter.  To get the NSDecimalNumber I need for the operations above I have been using "NSDecimalNumber(decimal:parsedNumber.decimalValue)".

Comment: Could you post an example of your currency string? Maybe that's the clue to your puzzle.

Comment: I can ("$546,000.06") but it doesn't parse correctly in the simplified example above so I'm not sure adding in the currency will help.